# Speeding up a Mono compilation / installation

Tags: mono

Can you configure and make a Mono installation on one server, then copy the files over to another server and simply run "make install" to install on the other server? Or do you absolutely have to rebuild the source on every machine?

If it's possible, what directories do I need to copy over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If the servers are identical (same distro and same version of that distro) you can copy files. If the servers aren't identical, it depends (copying between distros is likely to fail, between versions of the same distro may or may not work).

The easiest way to do it is to copy the entire repository (after running `configure && make`), and then just run `make install` on the target system, just like you suggested.

Usually mono installs into /usr/local by default (it depends a bit on the system), and if you don't have anything else there, you should also be able to just copy that directory to the target system (if you do have something there, you can create a file list before and after running `make install` do have a list of files you need to copy).

Comment: Any tips on how to create a file list so I can be sure I got everything?

Comment: Just run `find /usr/local` before and after `make install` on the first system (and save the output to different files)